# XSLT disable output escaping when disable-output-escaping is not supported

Tags: firefox, xslt

Since disable-output-escaping doesn't work on firefox (and isn't going to), whats the next best way of including raw markup in the output of an XSTL transform?

(Background: I've got raw HTML in a database that I want to wrap in XML to send to a browser to render. I've got control of both the XML and the stylesheet, but no control of the HTML, which may be badly formed (even for HTML!))

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XSLT is not about markup, it's about tree.

In XSLT1 you can't take a malformed input. In XSLT2 you can, but you loose xpath navegation of course.

So, without "disable-output-escaping" mechanism you can't output a posible malformed tree. And that's a feature!

Comment: Rats, I thought this was going to be the answer, but I was hopeing for something else. Ah, well.

Answer (score 1):

**You may put the offending text in a CDATA section**.

For example, this is a wellformed XML document:

```
<t><![CDATA[M & M < sufficient]]></t>
```

Here is an XSLT transformation, that puts the text nodes of selected elements (`<t>`) in CDATA sections:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes" />
 <xsl:output cdata-section-elements="t"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The result is:

```
<t><![CDATA[M & M < sufficient]]></t>
```

Without the `<xsl:output cdata-section-elements="t"/>` instruction the result would be:

```
<t>M &amp; M &lt; sufficient</t>
```